# Aggregating past and current values(monthly data) of Target column using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe like this below in pandas,

```
EMP_ID| Date|    Target_GWP
1     | Jan-2017|    100
2     | Jan 2017|    300
1     | Feb-2017|    500
2     | Feb-2017|    200
```

and I need my output to be  printed in below form.

```
EMP_ID| Date|    Target_GWP | past_Target_GWP
1     | Feb-2017|    600    |100
2     | Feb-2017|    500    |300
```

Basically I have monthly data coming in excel and I want to aggregate this Target_GWP for each EMP_ID against the latest(current month) and have to create a back up column in pandas dataframe for past month Target_GWP. So How will i back the past month target_GWP and add it to current month Target GWP

Any leads on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

#sorting and get last 2 rows
df = df.sort_values(['EMP_ID','Date']).groupby('EMP_ID').tail(2)
#aggregation
df = df.groupby('EMP_ID', as_index=False).agg({'Date':'last', 'Target_GWP':['sum','first']})
df.columns = ['EMP_ID','Date','Target_GWP','past_Target_GWP']
print (df)
   EMP_ID       Date  Target_GWP  past_Target_GWP
0       1 2017-02-01         600              100
1       2 2017-02-01         500              300
```

Or if need top value in `Target_GWP` instead `sum` use `last`:

```
df = df.groupby('EMP_ID', as_index=False).agg({'Date':'last', 'Target_GWP':['last','first']})
df.columns = ['EMP_ID','Date','Target_GWP','past_Target_GWP']
print (df)
   EMP_ID       Date  Target_GWP  past_Target_GWP
0       1 2017-02-01         500              100
1       2 2017-02-01         200              300
```

Comment: Thanks, Its helpful, just need a guidance on how will I handle it when I am getting new data monthly, Like when for Decemeber month, I have completely new dataframe which won't have data till november, so Do i need to backup this past data,but it will be overhead in memory.

Comment: Hmmm, can you edit question? If data in december what happens?

Comment: Basically data is received monthly and I need to have backup of past month Target_GWP to be stored in Database from dataframe , when I received current month Target_GWP.

Comment: Yes, but there is difference if december? Because if dates are convert to datetimes, `december with previous year` is less as januar current year and all working perfectly. Or something missing?

Comment: No, There is no difference in december. I get data daily in excel. I read them in pandas dataframe and apply transformation as you suggested above to aggregate it to a monthly data. And write back those to SQL DB. But in this process, past month data is being deleted and only current month data is stored into DB. Now I also want to have back of past month data in DB.

Comment: So need change format of dates like `2017-02-01` to `Feb-2017` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158068/discussion-between-jezrael-and-tilo).